# Function does not call after callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, child-process

hello all StackOverflowers :) have a good day.

I have a mouse.exe, that is a simple C++ App that receives via stdio "getmouse", "setmouse x y" and "movemouse x y", getting the mouse position and setting it respectively...

That app is working fine and can receive commands while running.

I created a 'mouse' module in a folder, with this index.js

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const EXE_ROUTE = __dirname + '\\mouse.exe';
var LOADED = false;

var Mouse = function (ready) {
    if(LOADED) return ready && ready();
    LOADED = true;

    var child  = spawn(EXE_ROUTE);
    var stdout = Mouse.in  = child.stdout;
    var stdin  = Mouse.out = child.stdin;
    var err    = Mouse.err = child.stderr;

    Mouse.out.write("movemouse 100 100"); // This Works
    Mouse.out.write("setmouse 20 20"); // This too

    ready && ready();
}

module.exports = Mouse;
```

And my entry point is app.js

```
var Mouse = require('./mouse');

Mouse(function () {
    console.log("Im here..."); // This prints
    Mouse.out.write("movemouse 100 100"); // This does not work.
});

Mouse.out.write("movemouse 100 100"); // This Works :)
```

Im a bit confused because the callback is called just after the Mouse() function, so it shouldnt be any difference between writing the line below the Mouse(function () { ... }); and writing it in the callback...

PD: Dont tell me "You dont need to use a callback here, bc i will do some async tasks then and i will need the cb"

Thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: until you write those async tasks inside, it will be the same. Try putting a setTimeout inside of it as a placeholder for you to see.

Comment: Does this code trigger a crash or is it just that single line `Mouse.out.write("movemouse 100 100");` doesn't work in your function?

Comment: No, it does not crash,, just doesnt work, i wrote setTimeout(() => Mouse.out.write("movemouse 100 100"), 1000); inside the index.js Mouse function and worked, then i wrote setTimeout(() => ready && ready(), 1000); and still happening the same error lol